# Prevent multiple callbacks for one collision with b2ContactListener?

Tags: ios, collision-detection, box2d, contacts

I downloaded Ray Wenderlich's simple contact listener from this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/606/how-to-use-box2d-for-just-collision-detection-with-cocos2d-iphone

Currently I am using the code below which is pretty much the implementation of the Ray's custom b2ContactListener in my CCLayer. But the problem is, is that there are *multiple callbacks* for one collision.

**Can someone show me how to make it so that the collision will only fire once until the 2 objects untouch and then retouch again?**

This is the code I am currently using:

```
std::vector<b2Body *>toDestroy; 
std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin(); pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) {
    MyContact contact = *pos;

    // Get the box2d bodies for each object
    b2Body *bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
    b2Body *bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
    if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL) {
        CCSprite *spriteA = (CCSprite *) bodyA->GetUserData();
        CCSprite *spriteB = (CCSprite *) bodyB->GetUserData();

        if ((spriteA.tag == 1 && spriteB.tag == 2) || (spriteA.tag == 2 && spriteB.tag == 1)) {
             NSLog(@"tag 1 hit tag 2");
        }
```

Thanks!

Edit1:

```
if ((hasDetectedCollision == NO) && ( (spriteA.tag == 1 && spriteB.tag == 2) || (spriteA.tag == 2 && spriteB.tag == 1) ) ) {
                hasDetectedCollision = YES;
                NSLog(@"tag 1 hit tag 2");
                [self doSomethingWhenCollisionHappens];
            }

- (void)doSomethingWhenCollisionHappens {
    //here you might want to remove an object because of a collision
    //or maybe change the color of the objects that collided
    //I can't provide more details of what you might want
    //to do without seeing more of your code
    //but when you are ready to start receiving collision updates again
    //set hasDetectedCollision to NO again
    [yesLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Yes: %d", yesNumber++]];
    hasDetectedCollision = NO;
}
```

Then in my init method:

```
hasDetectedCollision = NO;
```

**New Edit:**

```
if (!hasDetectedCollision && ((spriteA.tag == 1 && spriteB.tag == 4) || (spriteA.tag == 4 && spriteB.tag == 1))) {
            hasDetectedCollision = YES;
            [yesLabel setString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Yes:%d", yesInt++]];
            NSLog(@"tag 1 hit tag 4");
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Box2d, but from what you have described in your problem, this should help you out:

In your .h:

```
@interface foo : FooBar {
    BOOL hasDetectedCollision;
}
```

and in your .m:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    hasDetectedCollision = NO;
}
```

then simply replace

```
if ((spriteA.tag == 1 && spriteB.tag == 2) || (spriteA.tag == 2 && spriteB.tag == 1)) {
    NSLog(@"tag 1 hit tag 2");
}
```

with

```
if ((hasDetectedCollision == NO) && ( (spriteA.tag == 1 && spriteB.tag == 2) || (spriteA.tag == 2 && spriteB.tag == 1) ) ) {
    hasDetectedCollision = YES;
    NSLog(@"tag 1 hit tag 2");
    [self doSomethingWhenCollisionHappens];
}
```

and then:

```
- (void)doSomethingWhenCollisionHappens {
    //here you might want to remove an object because of a collision
    //or maybe change the color of the objects that collided
    //I can't provide more details of what you might want
    //to do without seeing more of your code
    //but when you are ready to start receiving collision updates again
    //set hasDetectedCollision to NO again
    hasDetectedCollision = NO;
}
```

Then whenever you are done doing whatever you want to do when you detect a collision, set hasDetectedCollision back to no, and you can start over.

Edit:

```
std::vector<b2Body *>toDestroy; 
std::vector<MyContact>::iterator pos;
for(pos = _contactListener->_contacts.begin(); pos != _contactListener->_contacts.end(); ++pos) {
MyContact contact = *pos;

// Get the box2d bodies for each object
b2Body *bodyA = contact.fixtureA->GetBody();
b2Body *bodyB = contact.fixtureB->GetBody();
if (bodyA->GetUserData() != NULL && bodyB->GetUserData() != NULL) {
    CCSprite *spriteA = (CCSprite *) bodyA->GetUserData();
    CCSprite *spriteB = (CCSprite *) bodyB->GetUserData();

    if(hasDetectedCollision == NO)
        NSLog(@"hasDetectedCollision == NO");

    if ((spriteA.tag == 1 && spriteB.tag == 2) || (spriteA.tag == 2 && spriteB.tag == 1)) {
         NSLog(@"tag 1 hit tag 2");
    }
```

If the if statement checking the state of hasDetectedCollision gets executed, then the problem is not with the boolean but with your collision detection.

Comment: What does this mean?: "Then whenever you are done doing whatever you want to do when you detect a collision, set hasDetectedCollision back to no, and you can start over." Do you reflect that in your code? Edit: I copied your code exactly and the collision code does not fire when they touch.

Comment: No; I don't reflect that in my code, but I will update my answer to do so.

Comment: Updated my answer, but make sure that hasDetectedCollision is being set to NO before checks begin. If it is, then the code I posted should work, because all it is checking for is if hasDetectedCollision is false, with no changes to your code. Try setting it to false right before the checks happen every time, just to make sure it will execute.

Comment: check my edit1, it still has the same issue. Maybe I am doing something wrong!

Comment: Ok so I fix the collision from not being called at all. It ended up being my sprite.tag numbers being wrong. Although it still gets called more than once for one collision.

Comment: How many times does it get called? The same number of times, or a diminished amount?

Comment: It gets called based upon how long the objects were colliding. Longer collision = More times and vice versa.

Comment: Well are you sure the hasDetectedCollision is being set to YES? Because if it is, then that isn't possible.

Comment: check my new edit. I decided to use that instead but it still has the same issue!

Comment: The problem is simple: the statements inside of doSomethingWhenCollisionHappens are being executed (and therefore hasDetectedCollision is being reset to NO) so quickly that it seems that hasDetectedCollision is never set to YES. So the code works as it should, but not how you want. Try adding [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1]; to the beginning of the doSomethingWhenCollisionHappens, and change the doSomethingWhenCollisionHappens call from [self doSomething...] to [NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(doSomethingWhenCollisionHappens) toTarget:self withObject:nil];

Comment: That code will sleep the thread for a second before setting hasDetectedCollision back to NO; that will (I think) give the two objects time to stop intersecting. It is by no means a permanent solution, but might give you the functionality/results you want. Modify as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what the rules are on SO about multiple answers, but this is an alternative for checking for collisions, one I use all the time:

In your viewDidLoad method:

```
NSTimer *g = [[NSTimer alloc] initWithFireDate:[NSDate date]
                                      interval:.1
                                        target:self
                                      selector:@selector(checkForCollisions)
                                      userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

NSRunLoop *r = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
[r addTimer:g forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[g release];
```

In your checkForCollisions method:

```
//without knowing what you are checking collisions for and
//why you are checking for collisions, I can't be too specific here
//but this code will do what you want

for(someObject* objectOfInterest in yourArrayOfObjectsToBeCompared)) {
    CALayer* layerOne = objectOfInterest.layer.presentationLayer;
    CGRect rectOne = layerOne.frame;
    for(someObject* compareObject in yourArrayOfObjectsToBeCompared) {
        CALayer* layerTwo = compareObject.layer.presentationLayer;
        CGRect rectTwo = layerTwo.frame;
        if(CGRectIntersectsRect(rectOne, rectTwo) && ![compareObject isEqual:objectOfInterest]) {
            //collision detected
        }
    }
```

This code just loops through your array of objects for comparing, then makes a CALayer copy of each object's presentation layer. This step is crucial because taking the regular frame of the object will not give its current position; that will give its destination position. The code then does the same again, comparing it with every other object in the array.

Comment: I don't think that is a great idea because I don't believe that is the most efficient way.

Comment: Alright. The practicality of this code depends on what you are comparing. In my case, I'm comparing an array of objects against just one rect, so there are no nested for loops and it is quicker. But I understand what you're saying.

Comment: Yea I think I need something specific to Cocos2D and Box2D, maybe a BOOL could work but I just think I am doing it the wrong way!